# What is the relation between the number of components in PCA vs. overall number of components?

Tags: machine-learning, pca

For example, if I have a 64-dimension problem, and 80% of the variance lies within just 12 components.

Is there some mathematical relationship that says something about the number of components that was required to express 80% of the variance of 64 components? i.e. that it *had* to be 12 components for a 64-dimension problem or does it entirely depend on the data in question.

Comment: Your question body and your title ask two different things. Did you mean overall number of variables in your title?

Comment: Apologies. I meant the overall number of dimensions.

Comment: Search the web for "scree plot."

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on the data in question.

For example, you can have a dataset where 100% of the variance lies in just 1 component: just set all but the first dimension to `0`. (Or put it all on any line.)

On the other extreme, you can have a dataset where it takes $X$% of the dimensions to get $X$% of the variance (up to rounding because the number of dimensions is discrete): for example, take the dataset to be the identity matrix, if the number of data points equals the dimension.

In general, the question is about the distribution of [singular values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value). The first case corresponds to having only one nonzero singular value; the second has all singular values equal.